# Razor pages .net Blog Path map to database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, razor-pages

I have a blog at domaintest.com/blog

And I want to have only the first level path map to a request. For example:

domaintest.com/blog/blog-post-title and not domaintest.com/blog/blog-post-title/ANYTHINGAFTER

I know how to get a HTTPGet request but how would I get the request value of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor Pages routing is based on file location. By default, the final segment in the URL must match the name of a file, or a folder with an `Index.cshtml` file in it. Any intervening segments represent folders rooted in the *Pages* folder.  A request for `domaintest.com/blog/blog-post-title/ANYTHINGAFTER` would only match if you have a folder and file structure like this:

```
Pages
    Blog
        blog-post-title
            ANYTHINGAFTER.cshtml <-- match on file name
            ANYTHINGAFTER
                Index.cshtml <-- match on folder name with index.cshtml in it
```

If you don't have a folder named *blog-post-title*, the URL will not match and the middleware will return a 404 Not Found. So your stated requirement is satisfied by existing behaviour.

On to your actual question, if you want the path of a request, use `Request.Path`.

Comment: Thanks, was assuming part of this but I am new to Razor.